# Xcode 7 stuck on "Validating application" when running application on iOS9

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, ios9

I'm trying to run application on my iOS 9 iPad with Xcode 7 and it gets stuck on "`Validating application`".

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: @matt Where is that setting, and how does it improve the underlying problem?

Comment: Hey there. Try reboot mac and reboot device. For me that worked

Comment: @matt where is that build setting? I didn't see it going through Xcode preferences.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? I have to deactivate my connexion to internet until it starts

Comment: I'm not using a proxy..That's strange

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Reboot your mac and/or restart Xcode. Fixed it for me.

Comment: All this Xcode environment is messed up, most of the answers for problems here are "restart" or "reboot" and they actually work. How can the developers work in a environment like that, outrageous!

Comment: Every single time there's an xCode related problem, I simply restart it before searching for a solution.

Comment: Problem still in 2020

Comment: Problem still in 2023.

Answer (score 10):

I had to restart my iphone also.

Answer (score 2):

I restarted mac, ipad, xcode multiple times, deleted derrived data and after many unsuccessfull tries, I was able to run my app on iPad.

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect and reconnect the data cable is worked for me. No need to reboot the iphone/ipad or Mac

Answer (score 1):

If you are not planning to release on AppStore and only creating an ad hoc build for testing, then do the following:

In Xcode 7, Goto Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme
From the left menu select "Archive" and Select "Distribution" from the "Build Configuration" drop down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with Xcode 8.3 and iOS 9 on the phone. Tried restarting Xcode, computer, the phone- none of them works.

Turns out, the phone was connected to a Wifi network without internet access. As soon as I connected the phone to another wifi with internet, the app installed fine.

The working theory is that the phone tries to do run validation against some remote Apple server, which fits the **"Validating application"** message. It's very unhelpful that it never times out or produce any meaningful error message, though.

Answer (score 1):

XCode 8.3, iOS10 here. Tried most solutions without much luck
X-Restart phone
X-Restart mac
X-Check WiFi (was connected to internet)
X-Unplug cable (tried both ends)
**O-Plug cable into a different USB port**

Hope that's an option for you!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to restart Xcode (as I wanted to maintain my undo buffer), but found the following worked:

1. Unplug the cable from iPhone
2. Uninstall the app from iPhone
3. Perform clean in Xcode
4. Plug phone back in
5. Set phone as the active target
6. Build
7. Run